# read out all the post title under a special category in wordpress from another system?

Tags: php, wordpress

how to read out all the post title under a special category in wordpresss from another system?

i know how to read out all the post title. the code:

```
 <?php
     $dbhost = 'localhost';
     $dbuser = '..' ;
     $dbpass = '...';
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    if(! $conn )
      {
           die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }
      $db_selected = mysql_select_db('..');
      if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}
$query = "SELECT post_title,ID FROM wp_posts ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 0 , 5";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

how to change the `query` code to get five post title under a special category .thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit different than the method you are currently trying to use, but I've implemented this in the past simply by using the feeds provided by WordPress.  This means that you don't have to worry so much about the DB schema changing, or making DB connections from remote servers.

All you have to do is hit the feed at:

http://www.somewebsite.com/category/categoryname/feed

-or-

http://www.somewebsite.com/?cat=123&feed=rss2

You can find more information on these feeds here:  http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds

Once you have the feed URL you want, you can parse it with [SimplePie](http://simplepie.org/), [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), or [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php).

Comment: thank you, if i want to use simplepie, could you make me with an example.

Comment: @dreamchaser, No, there are already tons of examples.  http://simplepie.org/wiki/setup/sample_page  The first one is what you're looking for.  Follow that and then cut it down to just what you need.

Comment: many thanks,SimplePie, DOMDocument, or SimpleXML which one is best to parser the feed?

Comment: @dreamchaser, for something as simple as this, I'd probably just use SimpleXML.  However, if you aren't familiar with it, and may use other parts of the feed (or other feed types) later, SimplePie is more robust for handling RSS.